# python csv to xlsx split file excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I need to convert large csv file to xlsx file, about 5 million rows, I need to set each output xlsx file to 100,000 lines and save it separately

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("k.csv")

data.to_excel("new_file.xlsx", index=None, header=True)
```

how should i add the row count parameter？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach will split your `k.csv` into chunks of `n` rows each. Each chunk is given a number e.g. `new_file001.xslx`

```py
import pandas as pd

n = 100000  # number of rows per chunk
df = pd.read_csv("k.csv")

for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n):
    df[i:i+n].to_excel(f"new_file{i:03}.xlsx", index=None, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to slice the csv as many times as needed.

e.g., to get rows 10000 to 19999, you would use

```
subset = data.iloc[10000:20000]
```

Comment: So how to save the files separately?